# what voltage rating do I have to observe at resonant frequency?

Tags: capacitor, inductor, high-voltage, resonance, cell-balancing

This is the schematic of the resonant switched capacitor cell balancing circuit.[image]
The problem is that at the resonant frequency when the capacitor and inductor impedances become equal and the total impedances become zero, the voltage drop on the inductor and capacitor is at their maximum. But that voltage, as far as I know, should be between 50-100 V or close to it. But in the simulation, it is somewhere between 40-45kv.[image]
What do you think is the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're simulating this circuit with ideal components (or at least nearly ideal, LTSpice adds 1mOhm ESR to inductors by default). This means that your resonant circuit has a ridiculously high Q factor.

Add some realistic ESR to the inductors and capacitors, i.e. something between 0.1 and 1 Ohm, and the voltages should start to come down.

You should also add free-wheeling diodes to all switching nodes to prevent excessive inductive free-wheeling voltages. This will help if the voltage spikes aren't caused by LC resonance, but rather by an inductor being suddenly disconnected.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is helpful. But what could possibly be the reason for an inductor to be disconnected?

Comment: Your switches are periodically connecting and disconnecting L1. That's what you want them to do, or not? You should add free-wheeling diodes antiparallel to the switches.